# How to track token consumption when using LlamaCpp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, langchain, llama

I am using langchain to define llm model. I use LlamaCpp and LLMChain:

```
!pip install huggingface_hub
!CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python --force-reinstall --upgrade --no-cache-dir --verbose
!pip -q install langchain

from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GGML"
model_basename = "llama-2-13b-chat.ggmlv3.q5_1.bin"

model_path = hf_hub_download(repo_id=model_name_or_path, filename=model_basename)

callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

n_gpu_layers = 32  # Change this value based on your model and your GPU VRAM pool.
n_batch = 512  # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of VRAM in your GPU.

# Loading model,
llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path=model_path,
    max_tokens=2500,
    n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
    n_batch=n_batch,
    callback_manager=callback_manager,
    n_ctx=2500, # Context window
)

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=my_prompts, input_variables=["long_name"])
chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)
```

How could i track token consumption when i run my chain? I found about get_openai_callback but it seems to only work with OpenAI

Comment: you need to implement custom callback manager for LlamaCpp, you can extend CallbackManager and implement you custom functions